# Upper bound for conditional expectation of spectral norm

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, upper-lower-bounds, spectral-norm

I am trying to understand an upper bound in the paper of [Zhang et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08757.pdf). This step is directly before equation (5.7) without any explanation. I even found the exact same step in two other papers without any explanation as well.

For a random matrix $C$ and a random vector $x$ the equation states

$$ \mathbb{E}[||(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C x||^2|\mathcal{F}] =
 \mathbb{E}[x^T \cdot(C^T(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C\cdot x |\mathcal{F}] $$
 $$\leq ||\mathbb{E}[C^T(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C]|| \cdot \mathbb{E}[x^Tx|\mathcal{F}]$$

where $\mathbb{1}\in \mathbb{R}^N$ denotes the vector with every entry equal to 1, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

It holds:

- $C$ and $x$ are conditionally independent given $\mathcal{F}$
- $C$ is row stochastic
- $\mathbb{E}[C]$ is doubly stochastic

My approaches so far fail at two points. The first one is the conditional expectation, which I do not know how to get rid of in this step (the paper does not state that $C$ is independent of $\sigma(x, \mathcal{F})$). Even if this would hold, which leads to my second point, the norm is inside the expectation and taking it out would lead to a lower bound according to Jensen's inequality.

You can find the same step in the following papers:

- [Suttle et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.06372.pdf) on page 16
- [Yan Zhang et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.09255.pdf) on page 9 in Lemma IV.9

Comment: coud you link the other papers?

Comment: @Exodd I edited the question and included the other papers. Thank you for having a look. They both reference the paper that I referred to first.

Comment: for the first question, $C_t$ is not included in the filtrations in the paper, and, (I didn't rad all of it, but seems reasonable) all the quantities in the filtration seem to be independent of $C_t$

Comment: @Exodd: Yes, $C_t$ is not in the filtration, only from the previous time steps, i.e. for $\tau \leq t-1$. However, it is not stated in the paper that it is independent of all the other things in the filtration, but only the conditional independence, stated in the first bullet point.
If it should be independent, it would be a far stronger assumption in my opinion. Though, I would be happy to accept it, if we can work out the second point :). Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm starting to believe they didn't use Jensen

Comment: Yes, I think so as well. To use Jensen, we would need equality for the lower bound, but Jensen holds with equality iff the random variable is constant or the convex function is linear. However, I think both of these assumptions do not hold in our case.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got (ignore for now the conditional part of the expectations, and suppose $C,x$ are independent)
$$
\mathbb{E}[x^T \cdot C^T(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C\cdot x ] =
\mathbb{1}^T 
(\mathbb{E}[C^T(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C]\odot \mathbb{E}[xx^T ])
\mathbb{1}
$$
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product.
$$
\mathbb{1}^T 
(\mathbb{E}[C^T(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C]\odot \mathbb{E}[xx^T ])
\mathbb{1}
\le n \|\mathbb{E}[C^T(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C] \|
\|\mathbb{E}[xx^T ] \|
$$
$$
\le n \|\mathbb{E}[C^T(I-\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T/N)C] \|
\mathbb{E}[x^Tx ] 
$$
where $n$ is the size of the matrices, and in the last step we used Jensen

Comment: I used your input and got the equation up to the constant $n$, under the assumption that the independence holds. I will think about it some more and will try to figure out the correct solution. If nothing new pops up, I will mark your answer as correct.
Again, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found another hint to this equation in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224387242_Broadcast_Gossip_Algorithms_for_Consensus) in the proof including equation (18). The used statement is for any operator $\Psi$ which has an ONB of eigenvectors $\psi_n$ with corresponding eigenvalues $E_n$. Let the eigenvalues be ordered, i.e. $E_0 \leq E_1 \leq \cdots \leq E_N$. We can represent any vector $f$ in the Hilbert space by $f = \sum_n \langle \psi_n, f \rangle \psi_n$. From this we get
\begin{align*}
\langle f, \Psi f \rangle &= \sum_n \langle f, \Psi \psi_n \rangle \langle \psi_n, f \rangle = \sum_n E_n \langle f, \psi_n \rangle \langle \psi_n, f \rangle \\
& \leq E_N  \sum_n \langle f, \psi_n \rangle \langle \psi_n, f \rangle = E_N  \langle f,  f \rangle
\end{align*}

For my proof to work, I need to assume that $C$ is independent of $\sigma(x, \mathcal{F})$. This is still not optimal in my opinion. With this we get
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}[x^T \cdot (C^T(I- \mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T / N) C \cdot x | \mathcal{F}] &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[x^T \cdot (C^T(I- \mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T / N) C) \cdot x | \sigma(x, \mathcal{F})] | \mathcal{F}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x^T \cdot \mathbb{E}[ (C^T(I- \mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T / N) C) | \sigma(x, \mathcal{F})]  \cdot x | \mathcal{F}] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[x^T \cdot \mathbb{E}[ (C^T(I- \mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T / N) C)]  \cdot x | \mathcal{F}] \\
& \leq ||\mathbb{E}[ (C^T(I- \mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T / N) C)] ||  \mathbb{E}[x^T  x | \mathcal{F}]. \\
\end{align}
Here I used the tower property of the conditional expectation for $\sigma(x, \mathcal{F}) \subset \mathcal{F}$. In the second step the $x$ could be taken out of the inner expectation, as it is $\sigma(x, \mathcal{F})$-measurable. The third step is possible due to the independence of $C$ to $\sigma(x, \mathcal{F})$. Finally, the result from above was used. Note that $\mathbb{E}[ (C^T(I- 11^T / N) C)]$ is a positive definite hermitian operator, therefore its largest eigenvalue is equal to the spectral norm.